# Orthogonal matrix which is neither rotation nor reflection?

Tags: linear-algebra

### Backgrounds

**Theorem**. For $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix $A$ on $\mathbb{R}$, **$A$ is a [Givens rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation) or a [Householder reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation#Householder_matrix).**

**Proof**. Suppose we have an orthogonal matrix,

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$

we have

$$
I = A^T A = \begin{bmatrix}
a^2 +c^2 & ab + cd \\
ab + cd & b^2 + d^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

thus we have the following formulas

1. $\Vert (a,c) \Vert_2 = 1$
2. $\Vert (b,d) \Vert_2 = 1$
3. $(a,c)(b,d)^T = 0$

So the solutions to the above formulas are given as

$$
\begin{aligned}
(a,c) &= (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) \\[8pt]
(b,d) &= \left(\cos (\theta \pm \pi/2), \sin (\theta \pm \pi/2) \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

So when 1) $ad - bc = 1$,

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}
$$

and when 2) $ad - bc = -1$,

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & -\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}
$$

The first case, by definition, corresponds to the **Givens rotation** by $\theta$.

We can also check that the second case corresponds to the the **Householder reflection** with respect to $v = (-\sin(\theta/2), \cos(\theta/2))$.

---

### Question

As far as I understood, for $3 \times 3$ matrix cases, a **Givens rotation** is a special case of rotation, where only two axes serve as the rotational axes, and **Householder reflection** is also a special case of reflection, where only a one-dimensional plane serves as the axis of the reflection.

So my question is : can we generalize, that

> For any $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix A on $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ is a **rotation** or **reflection**?

Comment: You're missing several details in your work on the $n=2$ scenario.  In general, $a,b,c,d$ are complex, and $\det A$ ranges in $\{e^{i\theta}:\theta\in[0,2\pi)\}$, not in $\{1,-1\}$.

Comment: @Aweygan I think I need to change the whole things into $\mathbb{R}$ cases... i.e. orthogonal matrices..

Comment: Probably the section of Wikipedia on higher dimensions, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Higher_dimensions will give you some idea of what goes on when $n>2$, also the paragraph following that, about "primitives".

Comment: Had a look at that link, Moreblue?

Comment: Are you still here, Moreblue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.